What benefit can I get from using GL_MAP_INVALIDATE_RANGE_BIT?
I don't know the aim of setting this bit when we map a buffer. We clearly know whether we're interested in the data in the buffer. So I think it is a bit flag indicating things to OpenGL. But, can we get any performance benefit from setting this bit?

I'm not 100% sure, but I think this flag states that the data doesn't need to be copied from the GPU memory to the host memory. This is useful when you only want to write to the mapped memory, but don't need to read the previous values.

@BDL When we want to read data from buffers, will OpenGL copy data in buffers from GPU's memory to CPU' memory?

Yes, it will copy the GPU memory to the CPU memory. GPU memory can't be read directly by the CPU, copying is the only way to access it.
